How to launch an application in the second desktop using PowerShell cmdlet
I need to run a PowerShell script using PowerShell or some other means in another desktop without switching back and forth across desktops. I could not find any cmdlet or other way to accomplish this. Could someone help?
$file1 = ".\configstore\config1.txt"
$filec = ".\config.txt"

$result1 = ".\results\applaunchresult1.txt"

$freq1 = 15
$iterations = 3

function MeasureAppLaunchTime {

    "Number of virtual desktops: $(Get-DesktopCount)"

    Sleep 1

    "Create a new desktop:"
    $NewDesktop = New-Desktop
    $OldDesktop = Get-CurrentDesktop

    "Number of virtual desktops: $(Get-DesktopCount)"
    "Number of new desktop: $(Get-DesktopIndex($NewDesktop))"
    "Name of new desktop: $(Get-DesktopName($NewDesktop))"

    $index = 1

    do {
        echo "Running Iteration - $index, Total - $iterations" 

        Copy-Item $file1 -Destination $filec 
        $NewDesktop | Switch-Desktop | Start-Process -FilePath .\AppTimer.exe -WindowStyle Hidden
        Sleep 10
        Switch-Desktop $OldDesktop

        echo "sleeping for next $freq1 sec"
        Start-Sleep $freq1

        $index++
    } while ($index -le $iterations)
}

config1.txt
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE

.\results\applaunchresult1.txt
Word
1
1000
0 1 0 0
1 1 0
0
0
1

Switch-desktop command switches back and forth to current active desktop which cause end-user to lose access to his current working desktop session for a while. I need to run this script for longer time. I could not find much on the net and seems no switch of start-process launch application in other desktop.

Use cmd which will search PATH instead of PSModulePath.  Check the command line options for cmd (Help cmd) from a cmd.exe window.

To run process on another machine invoke-command -computername machinexyz {<powershell code, etc.>} -asjob -credential (get-credential) should work. Work with \\machinexyz\c$ or \\machinexyz\sharename for copying to other machine if that's what you are after and is possible. Otherwise, to run process as another logged in user, you gotta wrap logic into a task scheduler executed PS script and set to run interactive, then remotely start the job.  All sorts of ways to do what you ask based on my interpretation of the wording in your question.

@BitcoinMurderousManiac, Thanks. I've to run the PS script in the same logged in user session but different desktop. The script which measures the Application launch time using Apptimer.exe opens an application and measure launch time, write to a file and closes application. The application should be commonly used apps like winword, explorer or chrome etc, The idea is to run the script independently in another desktop, so that the user won't get pop-ups of word or explorer.

I mean user won't get pop-ups of opening word or explorer in the desktop session being used by end-user.
